# Null parameter passed to skip list

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm getting "null Skip parameter was passed into argument position 1" error for lines 50 and 89 where I want to put the target/source module names into a skip list. I know the loop only executes if there is the out/in link (respectively), so how can it have a null parameter? I also check for the module name to be null, but the check does not make the error box pop up. Both loops execute for a certain number of objects and then stop when it gets to a particular point it doesn't like. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
  /*
Counts the number of non-obsolete requirements in a module and generates a count of number of objects with in/out links, organized by module name. Output is to a CSV file.

*/

pragma runLim, 0        //turn off timeout dialog
filtering off
Module m = current

/***********************
    populateBuffer
************************/
void populateBuffer(Buffer &b)
{
    Object o = null
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ srcMod
    ModName_ tarMod
    string targetMod
    string sourcMod
    int count = 0
    int outTotal = 0
    int inTotal = 0 
    int i = 0
    int n = 0

Skip OinLinks = createString
Skip OoutLinks = createString
Skip MinLinks = createString
Skip MoutLinks = createString
Skip OutOrphans = create        //list of object abs nos which do not have any out links
Skip InOrphans = create     //list of object abs nos which do not have any in links

string s = ""

for o in m do   
{
    if ((o."URB Object Type" "" == "Requirement") &amp;&amp; (o."TIS Status" "" != "Obsolete")) //always cast an attribute value as a string with empty quotes
    {
        for l in o-&gt;"*" do //for out links
        {
            tarMod = target(l)
            targetMod = name(tarMod)  //puts the target module of the current link into a string
            if (null targetMod) {errorBox "FAILURE FINDING TARGET MODULE!"; halt}
            print targetMod "\n"
            put(OoutLinks, targetMod, count + 1)        //puts all of the targetMods into the OoutLinks skip list
            n++ 
        }
            if (n &gt; 0) //check if this object has outlinks
            {
                for count in OoutLinks do//for each unique outlink target module of the current object
                {
                    if (find(MoutLinks, targetMod, i)) //if there is already a matching entry
                    {
                        delete(MoutLinks, targetMod) //remove the entry for that particular module name
                        put(MoutLinks, targetMod, i+1) //and re-enter it with count+1 in module level skip list
                    }
                    else {put(MoutLinks, targetMod, 1)} //if it is a new entry, add it with count 1
                }
            }
            else //if there are no outlinks,
            {
                int absno = o."Absolute Number"
                put(OutOrphans, absno, 1)       //This adds the absno of the current object to 
                                                //our orphan list
            }
            n = 0

        for lr in o &lt;-"*" do //for in links
        {
            sourcMod = name(source lr)  //puts the source module of the current link into a string
            if (null sourcMod) {errorBox "FAILURE FINDING SOURCE MODULE!"; halt}
            print sourcMod "\n"
            print "Source Modules \n"
            put(OinLinks, sourcMod, count + 1)      //puts all of the sourcMods into the OinLinks skip list
            n++ 
        }
            if (n &gt; 0) //check if this object has inlinks
            {
                for count in OinLinks do//for each unique inlink target module of the current object
                {
                    if (find(MinLinks, sourcMod, i)) //if there is already a matching entry
                    {
                        delete(MinLinks, sourcMod) //remove the entry for that particular module name
                        put(MinLinks, sourcMod, i+1) //and re-enter it with count+1 in module level skip list
                    }
                    else {put(MinLinks, sourcMod, 1)} //if it is a new entry, add it with count 1
                }
            }
            else //if there are no inlinks,
            {
                int absno = o."Absolute Number"
                put(InOrphans, absno, 1)        //This adds the absno of the current object to 
                                                //our orphan list
            }           


        delete(OinLinks)        //reset the OinLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object     
        delete(OoutLinks)       //reset the OoutLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object        

        n = 0
    }

    else continue
}


}

/************************************
    MAIN
*************************************/


string fName = "C:/Temp/LinkedObjectsInventory_Jan8.csv"
Stream outfile = write(fName)
Buffer b = create
populateBuffer(b)
outfile &lt;&lt; b
close(outfile)
delete(b)
// notify the user that the script is complete
ack "Inventory Complete."
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward issue-

The change I would make- replace this:

```
delete(OinLinks)        //reset the OinLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object     
delete(OoutLinks)       //reset the OoutLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object
```

with this:

```
    for count in OinLinks do //reset the OinLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object     
    {
        delete ( OinLinks , ( string key OinLinks ) )
    }

    for count in OoutLinks do //reset the OoutLinks list so we can start fresh for the next object
    {
        delete ( OoutLinks , ( string key OoutLinks ) )
    }
```

As part of your for each object loop, you were deleting the entire skip list rather than emptying it. This meant that on a subsequent loop, the program could not find the Skip list and threw an error. It's good to reuse skips rather than re-allocate them each time, but you have to empty the contents rather than call delete on the skip handle.

Good luck, and let me know if you have other issues!

Comment: Thanks Russell. I made the change as suggested, but now I am getting "incorrect arguments for (do)" for each FOR loop containing the PUT function.

Comment: Actually I have it running now that I made an additional change, rather than looping through the target/source module names in each out/in link, I needed to loop through each link. Do you know why one works and the other doesn't?

For example:
`
for l in o-> "*" do 
   {
    tarMod = target(l)
    put(OoutLinks, targetMod, count + 1)
`
works, but not:
`
for targetMod in o->"*" do 
   {
    put(OoutLinks, targetMod, count + 1)
`

Comment: The code you posted above loops through each link in an object. If you try and use 'for targetMod in o' ,  you are attempting to use a string in a for loop that is looking for a link parameter. 
Note: this is something you would do with incoming links- run 'for string_mod_name in o <-"*" do' - basically that would give you the source module name for each link, then you have to check if the source module is open to get the actual link info.
Something to keep in mind: links 'live' in the outgoing module.